# NextJS with Google Fonts

Tags: css, fonts, next.js, google-fonts

I'm learning next js but I have a problem... I tried to add a different font using @import from google fonts and everything works fine, but when I add a getServerSideProps() function the font doesn't work while with getStaticProps() everything works fine and I can't understand the problem. [This](https://github.com/filippo-brigati/filippobrigati) is the repo. Thanks

I expect to see a custom font

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Share links to your repo pages where: code is working, code is not working (for fonts). I didn't find the example of getStaticProps() in your repo

Comment: yes, in the repo that i linked i have used getServerSideProps() and the fonts will not changed to 'Inter' but if I use getStaticProps() the fonts will change to Inter. This however appears only after having deployed in vercel, when I do npm run dev the font is chosen correctly